# Trouble installing pygame using pip install

Tags: python, pygame, shared-libraries, pip

I tried: `c:/python34/scripts/pip install http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame`

and got this error:

```
Cannot unpack file C:\Users\Marius\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-b60d5tho-unpack\pygame 
(downloaded from C:\Users\Marius\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-rqmpq4tz-build, conte
nt-type: text/html; charset=utf-8); cannot detect archive format
  Cannot determine archive format of C:\Users\Marius\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-rqmp
q4tz-build
```

Please if anyone have any solutions please feel free to share them! 
I also tried 
`pip install --allow-unverified`, but that gave me an error as well.

Comment: Must you download and install it using an installer from https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads?

Comment: No not really, but installing it directly using the command "pip install pygame" doesn't get me anywhere either. Using this method i at least was able to download it 80 something % before it was unable to unplack. I'm not really sure why it's not working...

Answer (score 14):

This is the only method that works for me.

```
pip install pygame==1.9.1release --allow-external pygame --allow-unverified pygame
```

--

These are the steps that lead me to this command (I put them so people finds it easily):

```
$ pip install pygame
Collecting pygame
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pygame
  Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable (use --allow-external pygame to allow).
  No distributions at all found for pygame
```

Then, as suggestes I allow external:

```
$ pip install pygame --allow-external pygame
Collecting pygame
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pygame
  Some insecure and unverifiable files were ignored (use --allow-unverified pygame to allow).
  No distributions at all found for pygame
```

So I also allow unverifiable:

```
$ pip install pygame --allow-external pygame --allow-unverified pygame
Collecting pygame
  pygame is potentially insecure and unverifiable.
  HTTP error 400 while getting http://www.pygame.org/../../ftp/pygame-1.6.2.tar.bz2 (from http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml)
  Could not install requirement pygame because of error 400 Client Error: Bad Request
  Could not install requirement pygame because of HTTP error 400 Client Error: Bad Request for URL http://www.pygame.org/../../ftp/pygame-1.6.2.tar.bz2 (from http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml)
```

So, after a visit to http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml, I thought about adding the version number (1.9.1release is the currently stable one).

--

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks alot for taking the time, I think that could've worked but i was able to solve the problem in a different manner.

Answer (score 5):

If you get trouble when install pygame error about missing visual studio 10+. I have the answer:
The problem is not about have or not have visual studio, because I try many version but it not work. The problem is file: between `tar.gz` and `.whl`
so, this is the solution:

1) Download file:

> http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

Go here and download your pygame version, notice about x64 or x86 and python version. My system is x64 and python is 3.4 so I choose: `pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl`

2) Put it in some where to install:

I put it in "C:", so open cmd: and type:
cd C:\ (this is change location to C:)

3) Install

```
pip install C:\pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
```

Done !

Comment: For anyone reading, make sure you don't change the file name after you download.... It won't work if you do.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the compatible Pygame version was simply corrupted or broken. Therfore i had to install a previous version of python to run Pygame. Which is actually fine as most modules aren't updated to be compatible with Python 3.4 yet so it only gives me more options.

Answer (score 0):

I myself got this error(while using v3.10.0) and then I uninstalled the latest version and installed older version of python(v3.9.7) and it fixed the issue. Hope that works for you too. Honestly there are not many changes in the fix unless they jump from python3 to python4. so you dont need to update the python just for the sake of latest-ality