# How do I install Pygame with pip in Python 3.4?

Tags: python, installation, pygame

I have tried commands like

```
pip install pygame
```

or

```
pip install 'Pygame == 1.9.1release' --allow-external Pygame --allow-    unverified Pygame
```

suggested in other threads but and similars but they don't seem to work for me. Help me, please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble installing pygame using pip install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29548982/trouble-installing-pygame-using-pip-install)

Comment: This answer shows as a example how to install pygame from wheel using pip with both full path installed and not [How to install this wheel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150738/how-to-install-this-wheel)

Comment: `C:\Python34\Scripts\pip install C:\Python34\Scripts\pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl`   rename to your exact whl name of coarse

Answer (score 3):

I did this in Ubuntu and it worked for me with Python 3.4:

I ran a command which apparently upgraded `pip` and `setuptools` to the latest version, according to [this guide in the docs](https://packaging.python.org/installing/), but did it as a superuser. It might end up not being strictly necessary:

`sudo pip install -U pip setuptools`

Then, I ran the install command for Pygame as a superuser as well:

`sudo pip install pygame`

Comment: The little update might not be necessary because by the time I ran `pip install pygame` with `sudo` preceding I had already run said update.

Answer (score 2):

**In Windows**

1.open CMD

2.Path should locate where pip is installed   for me it is C:\Users\qwrht\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts>

if python is in other directory follow steps in link [CMD command to change directories](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=cmd%20cd%20command&oq=cmd%20cd%20comm&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.3396j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=cmd%20cd%20command%20in%20windows)

3.getting to the right path where pip is installed use command 
**pip install pygame.**in CMD

4.after Downloading pygame current version, Successfully installed pygame message will be displayed [image: as shown]

Comment: If Pip is properly installed, just going to C:\ should be enough. Then: pip install pygame  will get the job done.