# Pygame running error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this simple code to test if I have installed pygame properly.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
```

But on running I get the following error:

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Anyone got a solution on how I may fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show the entire traceback for the error, not just the one line. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

Try reinstalling `pygame`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037219/issues-installing-pygame?rq=1) notes that there are problems installing with pip vs. the provided installer. Make sure that the version you installed is the version for your machine (e.g. installing the 32-bit Windows version on a 64-bit Macbook).