# Can't install pygame no option to install to the registry

Tags: python, pygame

I have installed both python 2.7 32bit and python 3.5 32 bit but when I download and run either pygame 1.9.2a0 2.7 or 1.9.2a0 3.2 the installer does not give me the option to install to the registry. The only option is "Python from another location"

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

`pip install pygame==1.9.1release --allow-external pygame --allow-unverified pygame`

you can read further [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29548982/trouble-installing-pygame-using-pip-install)

Answer (score 0):

Use `pip` to pull it instead:

```
pip install pygame
```